# Display Admin Bar when Logged

Tags: admin-bar

I am unable to display the admin bar in the front end while the user is logged in to the admin.I have the wp_footer() and the checkbox in the user profile is checked too.

can some one please help.

Comment: If you have checked the option in the profile, it should show in the front end.

So can you check your theme's function.php file and look for `show_admin_bar` as a filter or function?

Comment: @MarutiMohanty I have tried using the show_admin_bar but yet no success

Comment: @tf the css is fine and its not made invisible

Comment: No i am working in my localmachine

Comment: Can you confirm if you were able to see the admin bar before and lately you have this issue?

Comment: as i use the twenty eleven theme it works fine

Comment: Once again, when using your desired theme, is the admin bar HTML in your website's HTML? It should be found near your closing `</body>` tag (due to `wp_footer`), and it should be enclosed in a `<div id="wpadminbar"...`. Also, what body classes are there? Do you have `admin-bar`?

Comment: This issue is clearly Theme-specific. What Theme are you using? Please post any relevant code from your Theme. You'll need to start in `functions.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce this error in a clean install?

Have you installed some new plugins in that site lately?

Have you tried to deactivate all contrib plugins and themes and see if the error persists when only core is active?

I fear we need some extra info to be helpful :(

Comment: I have deactivated all the plugins used and yet the problem persists.Have cleaned all the white spaces before and after the php tag too.Yet no luck.

Comment: thanks @khadkaboy it is weird if it isn't related to any contrib plugins and themes. Does the problem persists if you activate temporarily the "Twenty Thirteen" theme?

Comment: No in that case it works and i am trying to find the problem

Comment: Look into your `functions.php` file and see if you are positioning the page above the admin bar or something like that.